# Capture Cookie Content (or URL parameters, for tracking) on Woocommerce Checkout and show at Admin Order Page

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

There is any way to do this right?
I need to capture/collect an URL parameter (like GCLID ou UTM_SOURCE), store that and show on the admin order page detais. (see image).

I've tried adding the follow code to functions.php, but this doesn't work:

```
/**
 * @snippet       Add Meta Box @ WooCommerce Edit Order
 */
 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'bbloomer_order_meta_box' );
 
function bbloomer_order_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom_box', 'Tracking', 'bbloomer_single_order_meta_box', 'shop_order', 'advanced', 'high' );
}
 
function bbloomer_single_order_meta_box() {
    // global $post; // OPTIONALLY USE TO ACCESS ORDER POST
//Example 1:
    echo "GCLID: " . $_COOKIE[$gclid];
    echo "<br>";
//Example 2:
    echo $data['gclid'];
}
```

Thank you. =]

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to store it on the `order` post type custom metas.
you can save whatever data you need on `woocommerce_new_order` action.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {
    update_post_meta(
        $order_id,
        '_meta_key_name',
        $_GET['gclid'] 
    );
}, 10, 1);
```

please read [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) for more information about how to use this function.

after doing this you can the use [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to show the value in your admin page.

also make sure you check [Custom Meta Boxes](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) for more information about how to show your custom meta.